# Get Network type-Android 5.0

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

I have been trying to get the different Network types using NetworkInfo class.

```
ConnectivityManager conMgr =     (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(
                Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

NetworkInfo networkInfo[] = conMgr.getAllNetworkInfo();
for(int i=0; i<networkInfo.length; i++){         
              Log.i(networkInfo[i].getTypeName(),networkInfo[i].getDetailedState().toString());

           }
```

When I run this code in Nexus 4 which is updated to 5.0.1 Android Lollipop I get the following Network types and the detailed state.

```
WIFI=CONNECTED
MOBILE_CBS=DISCONNECTED
MOBILE_MMS=DISCONNECTED
BLUETOOTH=DISCONNECTED
MOBILE_FOTA=DISCONNECTED
MOBILE=DISCONNECTED
MOBILE_IMS=DISCONNECTED
MOBILE_HIPRI=DISCONNECTED
MOBILE_DUN=DISCONNECTED
MOBILE_SUPL=DISCONNECTED
```

The same code I check for Moto G which is updated to Android lollipop 5.0.2 I get the result as

```
MOBILE_VZW800APN=DISCONNECTED, 
MOBILE_MMS=DISCONNECTED,
BLUETOOTH=DISCONNECTED,
ETHERNET=DISCONNECTED,
MOBILE_HIPRI=DISCONNECTED,
MOBILE_DUN=DISCONNECTED,
MOBILE_SUPL=DISCONNECTED,
**36=DISCONNECTED**,
WIFI=CONNECTED,
MOBILE_CBS=DISCONNECTED,
WIFI_P2P=DISCONNECTED,
MOBILE_FOTA=DISCONNECTED,
MOBILE=DISCONNECTED,
MOBILE_IMS=DISCONNECTED
```

Can anyone please tell what this **36** represents? I checked with two different Moto G's I get the same result, both rooted and unrooted ones.